# Debugging a simple Android App

Tags: android, debugging

First , I create the skeleton app with activity, and it runs then I add more complicated codes, then the app crashed.

Right now, I disable all other features of all my app except the skeleton,which the onCreate method of activity. I would expect the app would work but it just crashed, it didn't go back to work stage.

On the Console, I don't see red errors as what caused the issue. It just have the pop up message of application has stopped unexpectedly, Please try again. I have no clue why even the skeleton isn't working.

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

  }
```

Comment: Could something with `res/layout/main.xml` be forming an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the DDMS perspective and check the LogCat to see what the error is.

See the following link for details about DDMS and how to use it.
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html

Comment: Weird, after I bring up DDMS, now the skeleton app runs OK now. Something smells funny.  So, why the app didn't run before DDMS?